# Calling super.equals and super.hashCode in child class?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

If I implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in both the parent and child classes, is it necessary to call `super.equals()` in `equals()` in the child class, e.g.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

  if (obj.getClass() != ChildClass.class) {
    return false;
  }

  return super.equals() && this.var == ((ChildClass) obj).var;

}
```

I am assuming that the parent class is not Object and is giving the correct definition of equals and hashCode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that's not necessary, and would probably be wrong.  Indeed, part of the reason why you're overriding `equal` is because `super.equals` doesn't give the correct behaviour (right?).

Or put another way, if `super.equals` gives the correct behaviour, you probably don't need to go to the trouble of overriding it.

But if you are overriding `equals`, then yes, you need to override `hashCode`, too.

Comment: `SuperClass.equals` can obviously only compare `SuperClass` instances and does not know anything about `SubClass`. That's why `SubClass` must override it, even if it is perfectly correct in terms of `SuperClass`. But it would be foolish to reimplement its behaviour in `SubClass` (or in each of many subclasses) instead of calling `super.equals` (before comparing the subclass parts), right?

Comment: Well, if value equality is being implemented, it can be necessary to call `super.equals()` to have inherited fields checked for equality...

Comment: actually, many times you only need to add checks for additional fields (as @Alan mentioned), so calling `super.equals()` is necessary.  additionally, if you are only adding fields, you don't _need_ to override `hashCode()`.

Comment: If `super.equals(o)`, then it should _always_ be the case that `this.equals(o)`, if this class and the super class satisfy the `equals` contract.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, you are correct, but this seems impossible to achieve unless the super class explicitly checks that the compared object has exactly the same class (and not a subclass of it).  I looked at a random class from the JDK: superclass java.awt.Color simply compares the RGB values of both objects (casting the other to Color).  Subclass javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.DerivedColor checks that the other instance is also DerivedColor.  So calling equals on Color with DerivedColor as argument can return true (if both have the same rgb values) while the inverse will always return false.

Answer (score 2):

If your super class doesn't implement equals, then calling super.equals will get you the Object implementation which only compares references, so in any normal equals implementation where you want to compare a business key it would actually cause a lot of false negatives.

That said, your implementation above really isn't any different semantically than the default equals implementation in Object since you are just using `==` for comparison.

As for hashCode, if you override equals you really should override hashCode in order to keep the contract of the two.  For instance, if you are using a business key for equals you should probably use the same business key for the hashcode so that two objects that are equal generate the same hashcode.